# al hacer el deploy de mi Api mis rutas dejaron de funcionar, cual puede ser el problema?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

en local la api funciona correctamente pero al deployarla me doy cuenta que mis rutas dinamicas no funcionan,el unico endpoint al que puedo acceder es al /api pero luego deberia poder pasar a, por ejemplo, /api/auth/login, pero al hacer requests no lo encuentra
dejo mi codigo abajo

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import connectDB from './db.js';
import router from './routes/router.js';
import cors from 'cors'

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

// Conexión a la base de datos
connectDB();

const corsOptions = {
    origin: "*",
  };

// Habilitar CORS
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Analizar solicitudes entrantes en formato JSON
app.use(express.json());

// Rutas de la API
app.use('/api', router);

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send({msg: 'Server Runing'})
})

// Puerto del servidor
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Iniciar el servidor
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

asi fue como hice mis rutas, al testear en el localHost esto hacia que las rutas fueran dinamicas. pero creo que al deployarlo ya no funciona

**router.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath, pathToFileURL } from 'url'


const router = express.Router()

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)

const PATH_ROUTES = __dirname

const removeExtension = (filename) =>{
    return filename.split('.').shift()
}



fs.readdirSync(PATH_ROUTES).forEach(async(file)=>  {
    
    const name = removeExtension(file)
    let route = path.join(PATH_ROUTES, file)
    
    try {
        
            const item = await import(pathToFileURL(route))
            router.use(`/${name}`, item.default)
        
    } catch (error) {

        console.log(error.message)
    
    }
})



export default router
```

aqui las rutas de autentiaacion a modo de ejemplo

**auth.js**

```
import express from 'express';

import { Login, Register, getUser } from '../controllers/auth.js'
import { registerValidator, validatorLogin } from '../validators/auth.js'
import { authMiddleware } from '../middlewares/session.js';
import { checkEmail } from '../middlewares/email.js';

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/register', registerValidator, checkEmail, Register)

router.post('/login', validatorLogin, Login)

router.get('/loged', authMiddleware , getUser)

router.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.send('auth')
})

export default router
```

espero que puedan ayudarme, la verdad no encuentro cual puede ser el problema aqui, aunque creo que puede ser por las rutas dinamicas que no funcionen como deberia.

Comment: No se ve que estés usando el "router" exportado en auth.js

Comment: Hola. Comprueba que las rutas se estén cargando correctamente.  Al depender de la carga dinámica para hacer rutas agregaste un poco de complejidad en tu código. Puede estar pasando que el `name` se este interpretando de otra manera, o que talvez no este cargando ningún fichero. Para descartar utiliza algunos console.log y haz de nuevo el deploy. Revisa tus logs.

Comment: @Legna muchas gracias, veré que puedo hacer

Comment: @ShiroiYami el "router" exportado se carga dentro de la función express.Router() esta interpreta automáticamente todas las funciones y las guarda, no es necesario llamarla para cada ruta